# how to solve highstocks error #15

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm not very proficient in javascript, but I've managed to cobble together this code that works to graph my data, but I'm getting an error #15 (Highcharts expects data to be sorted). I've searched around, but I need help to solve this in my specific instance.

Here is my code with a sample of the .csv data:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {


        var options = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temp'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

  /* 
     Data Series in .csv file are in columns, e.g.:

     1/24/2014 12:00:29 AM,74.64
     1/24/2014 12:01:29 AM,74.75
     1/24/2014 12:02:29 AM,74.86
     1/24/2014 12:03:29 AM,74.98
     1/24/2014 12:04:29 AM,74.98
     1/24/2014 12:05:29 AM,75.09
     1/24/2014 12:06:29 AM,75.09

     */

        $.get('temp2.log', function(data) {

            var lines = data.split('\n');

            lines = lines.map(function(line) {

                var data = line.split(',');

                sections = data[0].split(' ');
                section1 = sections[0].split('/');

                mm = parseInt(section1[0]-1);
                dd = parseInt(section1[1]);
                yyyy = parseInt(section1[2]);

                section2 = sections[1].split(':');

                hh = parseInt(section2[0]);
                mi = parseInt(section2[1]);
                ss = parseInt(section2[2]);

                section3 = sections[2];

                if(section3 == 'AM') hh = hh;
                if(section3 == 'PM') hh = hh + 12;

                formatDate = Date.UTC(yyyy, mm , dd, hh, mi, ss);

                /* console.log(formatDate); */

                data[0] = formatDate;
                data[1] = parseFloat(data[1]);

                return data;

                });


            var series = {
                data: lines,
                name: 'temp'
            };

            options.series.push(series);

                var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        });


    });
```

Comment: Are you sure 'temp2.log' is in that exact format?  Does it contain header or leading/trailing newlines?  I tried to replicate your problem with a jsFiddle but it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6ffmn/

Comment: How your series object looks like in this line  options.series.push(series); ?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code from

`var lines = data.split('\n');`

to

`var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);`

your problem it might be with the carriage return in the csv file